# Using AJax to prevent page redirect after submitting form

Tags: php, ajax, form-submit

Good Afternoon Everyone. I have a pretty unique situation which I cannot seem to find the answer for. I have a form which send to an email, but once the form is submitted it redirects to the php file which processes the information and sends the email. I've searched everywhere and seen that what I am trying to accomplish can be done using AJax, but I cannot seem to get it to work. I have my for load into a div which is contained on my index.html using JQuery. The problem is that when I submit it redirects to the php file, but I want it to remain inside the index.html containing it. I have placed my codes below. Thank you in advance.

```
<form name="inquiryForm" id="inquiryForm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"
    method="POST">              
        <fieldset>
            <legend>&#42; Required</legend>

            <br>

            First Name<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname;?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $fnameErr;?></span><br><br>

            Last Name<input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $lname;?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $lnameErr;?></span><br><br>

            Phone Number<input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone;?>"><br><br>

            Email Address<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span><br><br>

            <label>How did you find us?</label>
                <select name="how">
                    <option value=""> -- Please select -- </option>

                    <option>Google</option>

                    <option>Yahoo</option>

                    <option>Link from a website</option>

                    <option>Word of mouth</option>

                    <option>Other</option>
                </select><br><br>

            <label>Inquiry&#42;</label><br>

            <textarea name="inquiry" value="<?php echo $inquiry;?>" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $inquiryErr;?></span><br><br><br>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">

            <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Below is my php file

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "my email address";
$subject = "Ism Clothing Contact Form Submission";

// define variables and set to empty values
$fnameErr = $lnameErr = $emailErr = $inquiryErr = "";
$fname = $lname = $email = $inquiry = "";
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$how = $_POST['how'];

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
        $fnameErr = "First Name is required";
    } else if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
        $lnameErr = "Last Name is required";
        } else {
             $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
             $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);

             if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname)) {
               $fnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
             } else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lname)) {
               $lnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
             }
        }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
     }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["inquiry"])) {
     $inquiryErr = "Please enter questions comments, or concerns";
    } else {
     $comment = test_input($_POST["inquiry"]);
    }
}

function test_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

/* Format form data for email */
$message = "Hello!

Ism Clothing contact form has been submitted by:

Name: $fname $lname
E-mail: $email
Phone #: $phone

How did he/she find it? $how

Comments:
$inquiry

End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);
```

?>

and below is the Jquery code which loads my contact.php (form) into my main page (index.html)

```
$("#contact").on("click", function(){
    $("#content").load("contact.php");
});
```

I am using that code above in my index.js to load contact.php into a div in my index.html.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: If you're using Ajax, then you don't submit the form like a normal HTML form, you submit it via Ajax, which you are *not* doing.

Comment: Would I have to remove the action?

Comment: I apologize, but I am new to using ajax. I understand that I have to use it to submit the form the my php, but I just don;t understand how to go about doing this.

Comment: Loading the page with `$("#content").load("contact.php");` is not submitting the form via Ajax.  Look for some Ajax tutorials on submitting a form, not loading a page.

Comment: Sidenote: Do add proper mail headers, otherwise your emails will more than likely be treated as and end up in Spam. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I apologize, should have clarified that piece code more. I am using that in my index. js to load contact.php into my index.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out :

```
 $("#inquiryForm").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: $this.attr('action'),
       data: $this.serialize(),
       success : function(){
          alert('Done');
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Should I leave my form action blank?

Comment: @AJ_, Not necessary. The `e.preventDefault();` prevents it from doing the normal submit. Leaving the action there will allow the form to be submitted when Javascript is off.

Comment: @AJ_ no you shouldn't. See how he fetches the ajax `url` part via the form action with `$this.attr('action');`.

Comment: @Simo do you mean I should replace the current action which is PHP_SELF to the url of my php form?

Comment: not your html form, but your php file where you do all the processing (validation, sending mail...)

Answer (score -1):

You've got a bit of confusion.

Using Ajax you don't need a form at all: you show input fields to the user, then at a button press you build an Ajax request and wait for a reply. This mean that your page do not move from where it stands.

Instead, when submitting a form, HTML expects a place where to output the form results: by submitting you are navigating to an url, after all.

Now, you have two solutions:
1) learn how to use Ajax.
2) put an hidden **iFrame** on the page, give it an ID, set the form target to that ID and add an handler to the iFrame loaded event

Comment: No hidden iFrames, please.

Comment: I would like to use ajax. Would you be able to explain to me how I can do this using ajax?